# select elements having href attribute not starting with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.el[href^="view.php"]').css('background', 'gold');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=323'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=525'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'index.php'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'about.php'>lorem</a>
```

The above works fine but now I need elements having `href` **not** starting with `view.php`.

I tried without success:

```
$('.el[href^!="view.php"]').css('background', 'gold');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [*Attribute Starts With Selector*](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector inside jQuery's [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```js
$('.el').not('[href^="view.php"]').css('background', 'gold');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=323'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=525'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'index.php'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'about.php'>lorem</a>
```